# Getting the full path for an Item selected through IVsHierachy

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, vspackage

Hi I'm making a visual studio package which creates a context menu in the solution explorer when certain types of file are right clicked. I have the menu working but I need to grab the full path rather than the filename. I do this because selecting an option in the context menu opens a commandline program that takes the full path as a paremeter.

Right now it looks like this:

```
    foreach (var ItemSelected in vsItemSelections)
                    {
                        object value;
                        hierarchy.GetProperty(ItemSelected.itemid, (int) __VSHPROPID.VSHPROPID_Name, out value);
                        if (value != null && value.ToString().EndsWith(".rst"))
                        {
                            cmd.Visible = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cmd.Visible = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
```

So I can make the command visible in the context menu if .rst files are selected but obviously I need the full path. I've tried everything I can think of but this is a totally new area to me.

I have a solution that already works using an ENVDTE80.DTE application object but it seems awfully clunky when it runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It ultimately depends on the type of hierarchy (not all items supports a "full path" concept), but for most hierarchy, this method should get back what you need:

```
IVsHierarchy.GetCanonicalName(uint itemid, out string pbstrName);
```